# Boostrap (5) Javascript is not working after package.json revision (Ruby on Rails 6)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, package.json

I was trying to update some versions in my package.json (basically Bootstrap 5 final that I already had in beta) which I did. An then, some more. At some point, all the bootstrap JS stoped working. I don't get any error in the browser console or the server log. It is like clicking links with '#'

I use extensively dropdowns and modals, so right now I am totally deactivated.

I am aware that Bootstrap needs popper.js for the JS work, and have checked several times they are included in package.json and yarn.lock. I've have even rolled back git with 10 versions earlier, but it keeps like that.

I have checked also the 'javascript_pack_tag' in application.html.erb. I don't know what else to do.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "redvi",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.9.2",
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "5.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.1",
    "popper": "^1.0.1",
    "stimulus": "^2.0.0",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  }
}
```

in **application.html.erb** I have included:

```
<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Although I have a similar app working with this, also:
**javascript/packs/application.js**

```
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import "channels"

Rails.start()
Turbolinks.start()
ActiveStorage.start()

// Uncomment to copy all static images under ../images to the output folder and reference
// them with the image_pack_tag helper in views (e.g <%= image_pack_tag 'rails.png' %>)
// or the `imagePath` JavaScript helper below.
//
// const images = require.context('../images', true)
// const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)
import { Application } from "stimulus"
import { definitionsFromContext } from "stimulus/webpack-helpers"

import "controllers"
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap'
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap";

const application = Application.start()
const context = require.context("./controllers", true, /\.js$/)
application.load(definitionsFromContext(context))
```

Bootstrap classes in buttons an such are fine. It is the JS interactions what I can't get.

I don't know if I am missing another important file, if yes, let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with yarn caché + a change of versions in package json.
For some reason, After updating the version, it kept working with the old ones and I didn't bump into the problem until much later. I had to clean all the files from yarn and node modules and roll back to the previous version.